# Change the url of a pagination in grails

Tags: url, grails

Can anyone help me how to change the url displayed in the address bar in grails.

Here I have a data table. Once i click on the pagination list displayed at the bottom, lets say 2, then the url changes to

```
  http://localhost:8080/test/account/list?searchText=%25&paginationNumber=10&advancedSearchText=&searchCriteria=&searchOperator=&offset=10&max=10
```

from

```
http://localhost:8080/test/account/list
```

Now I need the same url

```
http://localhost:8080/test/account/list
```

even i navigate to different pages.

Whether it is possible to override the url in grails.

Comment: Can anyone know the answer

Comment: You do need max and offset params for pagination, so you can't leave url exactly the same.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your original page was the result of a form POST, with these additional parameters as fields on the form. When you use `<g:paginate>` it generates a normal `<a>` link for each button, which means a GET request, so the params go into the URL.

You might be able to get it to do what you want with a bit of JavaScript, wrapping a POST form around the paginate buttons with hidden fields for the additional data, and attach an event handler to the pagination links to trigger a submit of the form.

Alternatively, store the extra parameters server side in the session instead of passing them back and forth, and accept the `offset` and `max` in the URL.